# How to Make Images Center In Columns?

Tags: css

For some reason the images in the columns [on this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/professional-success/) are not centering while the `<p>`s are. They are both encased in the same divs (#event).

```
.event {
    position:relative;
    right:auto;
    left:auto;
    width: 315px;
    height:100%;
    margin:5px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
img.event {
    position:relative;
    align:center;
    width:315px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
p.event {
    position:relative;
    right:auto;
    left:auto;
    width:315px;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1.2pt;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #333333;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following to img.event:

```
right:auto;
left:auto;
```

Comment: This didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct your markup first.  You have p tags nested inside anchor tags.  I think this is giving you the illusion that your p tags are centered when in fact they are not.

I'm not trying to be harsh, but it would probably be easier to debug your issue when you have correct markup.

Comment: Okay :) I'll work in putting the p tags in the right place to begin with